# Residue at $0$ of $\frac{1-\cos z}{z^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How do I calculate $Res(g,0)$ of $g=\frac{1-\cos z}{z^4}$?

Comment: Laurent series. Taylor series of $1 - \cos z$, divide by $z^4$. Of course you can short-cut it and say the function is even.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does an even function imply that the Laurent series does not have any terms in which $z^k$ with $k$ odd?

Comment: Yup. Even more, for an even $f$, you have $\operatorname{Res} (f, -z) = - \operatorname{Res} (f,z)$. (Write out the integral to see it.) Can you guess what relation the residues at $z$ and $-z$ have for an odd function?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know what integral you mean?

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, I know the definition: $Res(f,z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C f(z)dz$  (if that's what you are getting at?) but I don't know yet how to use it, since I am new to complex analysis.

Comment: Yes, that integral is what I mean. If you parametrise the curve around $z_0$ by $\alpha \colon [-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb{C}$, you get $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(\alpha(t))\alpha'(t)\,dt.$$ Now, for the residue in $-z_0$, use the curve $\beta(t) = -\alpha(t)$.

Comment: Just a few hours ago you asked about the Laurent series of $\;\frac{1-\cos z}{z^2}\;$ , @student . Didn't you learn from the answer(s) there? It's practically the same method!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Expand the numerator into its Taylor form, then determine the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ of $g$.

Comment: I see that this coefficient is 0, so apperently $Res(g,0)=0$. Should I always look at the coefficient in front of $z^{-1}$ to find the residue? And if so why?

Comment: @student: Sometimes this is taken to be the definition. If you consider your definition, though, considering how many derivatives are involved, the factor you multiply by, and finally, taking the limit to $0$. What you are left with is precisely the coefficient of $z^{-1}$. Depending on the problem, determining $Res(g,z)$ is sometimes easier this way.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos(z) = 1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} - ... \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!} + ... $ , so $1-\cos z=\frac{z^2}{2!} - \frac{z^4}{4!} + {z^6\over 6!}- ... \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}  ... $
now when you divide by $z^4$, do you see any term of the form ${1\over z}$? so residue is $0$